# Making a queue program

Tags: c, queue

Can someone help me making a queue program. I want to set the `array[0]` to be `array[1]` just in display but in real I am adding value at `array[0]`. I got how to run the add function to it, but I can't do the view and delete command that will view from ex. array[0] to array[4], when displayed array[1] to array[5] with the value inserted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define p printf
#define s scanf

int rear = 0;
int front = 0;
int *q_array = NULL;
int size = 0;

main()
{
    int num, opt;
    char cont[] = { 'y' };
    clrscr();
    p("Queue Program\n\n");
    p("Queue size: ");
    s("%d", &size);
    p("\n");

    if(size > 0)
    {
        q_array = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        if(q_array == NULL)
        {
            p("ERROR: malloc() failed\n");
            exit(2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        p("ERROR: size should be positive integer\n");
        exit(1);
    }

while((cont[0] == 'y') || (cont[0] == 'Y'))
{
    clrscr();
    p("Queue Program");
    p("\n\nQueue size: %d\n\n", size);
    p("MAIN MENU\n1. Add\n2. Delete\n3. View");
    p("\n\nYour choice: ");
    s("%d", &opt);
    p("\n");

    switch(opt) {
        case 1:
            if(rear==size)
            {
                p("You can't add more data");
            }
            else
            {
                p("Enter data for Queue[%d]: ", rear+1);
                s("%d", &num);
                add(num);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            delt();
            break;
        case 3:
            view();
            break;
    }
    p("\n\nDo you want to continue? (Y\/N)");
    s("%s", &cont[0]);
}
}
add(int a)
{
    q_array[rear]=a;
    rear++;
}
delt()
{
    if(front==rear)
    {
        p("Queue Empty");
    }
    else
    {
        p("Queue[%d] = %d removed.", front, q_array[front]);
        front++;
    }
}
view()
{
    int i;
    for(i=front;i<=rear;i++)
        p("\nQueue[%d] = %d", i, q_array[i]);
}
```

Comment: So what output do you get, and what did you expect to get instead?

Comment: Don't use stuff like `#define p printf`! It's ineffective as an obfuscation, but it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: It is easier and more correct to type `perror( ` than `p( "ERROR`.  Errors messages belong on stderr, and should include system error messages.  Please use `perror`.

Comment: Note that you should declare and define functions that return no value with a return type of `void`, but `main()` should return an `int` (and since you are using implicit types, you must return the value explicitly; C89 requires that, and C99 requires explicit return types).  You need to use compiler options that generate more warnings and fix the warnings that are given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. One serious problem here is

   ```
   char cont[] = { 'y' };
   ...
   s("%s", &cont[0]);
   ```

   You've only reserved **one** byte but `scanf` will write at least 2 bytes, meaning that you are going to have a buffer overflow and then the overall behaviour is unpredictable. If you want to read a single character then use`"%c"` as a pattern but the problem here is that characters will be in the buffer for the next read, so you are going to have to clear the buffer.

   It's much easier to do:

   ```
   char line[1024];
   fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
   if(line[strlen(line)-1] == '\n')
       line[strlen(line)-1] = 0;

   if(strcmp(line, "Y") == 0 || strcmp(line, "y")==0)
   ```

   It's a little more code but it's safer this way.
2. There are many queues, there are fifo, lifo, and depending on it you choose how to build it
3. When dealing with queues, it's better to use function names like `push`, `pop` and `top` because they are widely used among other programmers and queue libraries. Use
   these names instead.
4. In your case, instead if remembering with `front` and `rear` you should use
   `memmove` instead and use a variable `len` to count the current number of
   elements in the node. Once you've popped one element, you gained new space for
   more elements.

Also, try to use fewer global variables and more encapsulation: (in my example I am 
not going to care about `malloc` returning `NULL`, I want to keep it short)

```
#include <string.h> /* for size_t */

typefed struct {
    size_z len;
    size_z max_size;
    int    *data;
} queue;

void queue_init(queue *q, size_t max_size)
{  
    q->len      = 0; 
    q->max_size = max_size;
    q->data     = malloc(max_size * sizeof *(q->data));
    /* this is a good trick!
     * If you need to change the datatype of 'data',
     * you only need to change the definition of it.
     * This code is valid for any type */ 
}  

int push(queue *q, int data)
{  
    if(q->len == q->max_size)
        return 0; /* not enough space */ 

    q->data[q->len++] = data;
    return 1;
}

int top(queue *q, int *data)
{
    if(q->len == 0)
        return 0; /* no elements in the queue */
    *data = q->data[0];
    return 1;
}

int pop(queue *q, int *data)
{
    if(top(q, data) == 0)
        return 0;

    memmove(q->data, q->data + sizeof *(q->data), q->len--);
    return 1;
}
```

BTW:

```
#define p printf
#define s scanf
```

Just like Daniel Fischer said, this is ugly; don't do that.