# timers in linux in c

Tags: c, linux, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loops/timers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540245/loops-timers-in-c)

I've been reading about timers for the last 3 days and I'm unable to find anything useful, I'm trying to understand it in real example, can somebody help me figure out how to setup an alarm for the below program.

How can I set a a timer so that it will send 2 args, one is the array name, and the second one is the number to be deleted, I know the below is not safe in anyway, I'm just trying to understand how use alarms with args to call a function.

please note that the environment is Linux, and also I appreciate any link with a working C example.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int delete_from_array(int arg) ;


    int main()
    {

    int a[10000], i, y ;
    //how to set timer here for to delete any number in array after half a second
    for (y=0; y < 100; y++) {


        for (i=0; i<sizeof(a) / sizeof(int); i++)
            a[i] = i;
    sleep(1);
    printf("wake\n");
    }

    }

    int delete_from_array(int arg) 
    {
    int i, a[1000], number_to_delete=0;

    //number_to_delete = arg->number;

    for (i=0; i<sizeof(a); i++)
        if (a[i] == number_to_delete)
            a[i] = 0;
    printf("deleted\n");

    }
```

What I'm trying to do is that I have a hash which has has values to be expired after 1 seconds, so after I insert the value into the hash, I need to create a timer so that it will delete that value after let's say 1 second, and IF I got a response from the server before the that interval (1 second) then I delete the value from the hash and delete the timer, almost like retransmission in tcp

Comment: This `i<sizeof( (sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)) )` is probably not what you intended. That's `i < sizeof(size_t)`, you wanted `i < sizeof a / sizeof a[0]`, I believe. Also in the last `for` loop.

Comment: You may want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540245/loops-timers-in-c) question

Comment: my mistake, I meant sizeof(a) / sizeof(int), I'll modify the code.

Comment: you have at the bottom `if (a[i] = number_to_delete)`. You probably mean `if (a[i] == number_to_delete)`. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652918/making-a-queue-program/12654055#12654055 for a dynamic list. Btw. what has that to do with timers at all?

Comment: You're right Pablo, that was a typo, what I'm trying to do is that I have a hash which has has values to be expired after 1 seconds, so after I insert the value into the hash, I need to create a timer so that it will delete that value after let's say 1 second, and IF I got a response from the server before the that interval (1 second) then I delete the value from the hash and delete the timer, almost like retransmission in tcp

Comment: The short answer is that you can do it - but not quite the way you have it.  The long answer is that it is a *long* answer and showing you how to code it is probably more work than most people want to invest in the answer.  Depending on exactly how you want to do it there are probably a half dozen options.  Suggest you look at the `create_timer`/`timer_settime`/`delete_timer` family of system calls.  Buried in sigevent is a sival_ptr you can use to point to a struct containing your array addr and index to delete.

Comment: Sorry.  `timer_create`/`timer_delete`.

Comment: Thanks Duck, so how many timers I can set in a program? is there a limit or a recommendation?

Comment: Going by memory, numner of timers is limited by the number of realtime signals which can be queued.  You can get that by sysconf(_SC_SIGQUEUE_MAX) or I think the constant _POSIX_SIGQUEUE_MAX.  It is advisable to keep the usage low for your sanity's sake as much as anything.

Comment: @Duck: Since 2.6.8, it's actually limited by `RLIMIT_SIGPENDING` (use `getrlimit(RLIMIT_SIGPENDING, &rlim)` with `struct rlimit rlim;`), according to the NOTES section of the current `man timer_create` man page. There may be other, system-wide limits imposed by the kernel, so you cannot really rely on getting that many timers in practice.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do you want to use signals or threads?

First, set up the signal handler or prepare a suitable thread function; see [man 7 sigevent](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/sigevent.7.html) for details.

Next, create a suitable timer, using `timer_create()`. See [man 2 timer_create](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) for details.

Depending on what you do when the timer fires, you may wish to set the timer to either one-shot, or to repeat at a short interval afterwards. You use `timer_settime()` to both arm, and to disarm, the timer; see [man 2 timer_settime](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_settime.2.html) for details.

In practical applications you usually need to multiplex the timer. Even though a process can create multiple timers, they are a limited resource. Especially timeout timers -- which are trivial, either setting a flag and/or sending a signal to a specific thread -- should use a single timer, which fires at the next timeout, sets the related timeout flag, and optionally send a signal (with an empty-body handler) to the desired thread to make sure it is interrupted. (For a single-thread process, the original signal delivery will interrupt blocking I/O calls.) Consider a server, responding to some request: the request itself might have a timeout on the order of a minute or so, while processing the request might need connection timeouts, I/O timeouts, and so on.

Now, the original question is interesting, because timers are powerful when used effectively. However, the example program is basically nonsense. Why don't you create say a program that sets one or more timers, each for example outputting something to standard output? Remember to use `write()` et al from `unistd.h` as they are [async-signal safe](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html), whereas `printf()` et cetera from `stdio.h` are not. (If your signal handlers use non-async-signal safe functions, the results are undefined. It usually works, but it's not guaranteed at all; it may just as well crash as work. Testing will not tell, as it is *undefined*.)

---

Edited to add: Here is a bare-bones example of multiplexed timeouts.

(To the extent possible under law, I dedicate all copyright and related and neighboring rights to the code snippets shown below to the public domain worldwide; see [CC0 Public Domain Dedication](http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/). In other words, feel free to use the code below in any way you wish, just don't blame me for any problems with it.)

I used old-style GCC atomic built-ins, so it should be thread-safe. With a few additions, it should work for multithreaded code too. (You cannot use for example mutexes, because `pthread_mutex_lock()` is not async-signal safe. Atomically manipulating the timeout states should work, although there might be some races left if you disable a timeout just when it fires.)

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define   TIMEOUTS       16
#define   TIMEOUT_SIGNAL (SIGRTMIN+0)

#define   TIMEOUT_USED   1
#define   TIMEOUT_ARMED  2
#define   TIMEOUT_PASSED 4

static timer_t               timeout_timer;
static volatile sig_atomic_t timeout_state[TIMEOUTS] = { 0 };
static struct timespec       timeout_time[TIMEOUTS];


/* Return the number of seconds between before and after, (after - before).
 * This must be async-signal safe, so it cannot use difftime().
*/
static inline double timespec_diff(const struct timespec after, const struct timespec before)
{
    return (double)(after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec)
         + (double)(after.tv_nsec - before.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
}

/* Add positive seconds to a timespec, nothing if seconds is negative.
 * This must be async-signal safe.
*/
static inline void timespec_add(struct timespec *const to, const double seconds)
{
    if (to && seconds > 0.0) {
        long  s = (long)seconds;
        long  ns = (long)(0.5 + 1000000000.0 * (seconds - (double)s));

        /* Adjust for rounding errors. */
        if (ns < 0L)
            ns = 0L;
        else
        if (ns > 999999999L)
            ns = 999999999L;

        to->tv_sec += (time_t)s;
        to->tv_nsec += ns;

        if (to->tv_nsec >= 1000000000L) {
            to->tv_nsec -= 1000000000L;
            to->tv_sec++;
        }
    }
}

/* Set the timespec to the specified number of seconds, or zero if negative seconds.
*/
static inline void timespec_set(struct timespec *const to, const double seconds)
{
    if (to) {
        if (seconds > 0.0) {
            const long  s = (long)seconds;
            long       ns = (long)(0.5 + 1000000000.0 * (seconds - (double)s));

            if (ns < 0L)
                ns = 0L;
            else
            if (ns > 999999999L)
                ns = 999999999L;

            to->tv_sec = (time_t)s;
            to->tv_nsec = ns;

        } else {
            to->tv_sec = (time_t)0;
            to->tv_nsec = 0L;
        }
    }
}


/* Return nonzero if the timeout has occurred.
*/
static inline int timeout_passed(const int timeout)
{
    if (timeout >= 0 && timeout < TIMEOUTS) {
        const int  state = __sync_or_and_fetch(&timeout_state[timeout], 0);

        /* Refers to an unused timeout? */
        if (!(state & TIMEOUT_USED))
            return -1;

        /* Not armed? */
        if (!(state & TIMEOUT_ARMED))
            return -1;

        /* Return 1 if timeout passed, 0 otherwise. */
        return (state & TIMEOUT_PASSED) ? 1 : 0;

    } else {
        /* Invalid timeout number. */
        return -1;
    }
}

/* Release the timeout.
 * Returns 0 if the timeout had not fired yet, 1 if it had.
*/
static inline int timeout_unset(const int timeout)
{
    if (timeout >= 0 && timeout < TIMEOUTS) {
        /* Obtain the current timeout state to 'state',
         * then clear all but the TIMEOUT_PASSED flag
         * for the specified timeout.
         * Thanks to Bylos for catching this bug. */
        const int  state = __sync_fetch_and_and(&timeout_state[timeout], TIMEOUT_PASSED);

        /* Invalid timeout? */
        if (!(state & TIMEOUT_USED))
            return -1;

        /* Not armed? */
        if (!(state & TIMEOUT_ARMED))
            return -1;

        /* Return 1 if passed, 0 otherwise. */
        return (state & TIMEOUT_PASSED) ? 1 : 0;

    } else {
        /* Invalid timeout number. */
        return -1;
    }
}


int timeout_set(const double seconds)
{
    struct timespec   now, then;
    struct itimerspec when;
    double            next;
    int               timeout, i;

    /* Timeout must be in the future. */
    if (seconds <= 0.0)
        return -1;

    /* Get current time, */
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now))
        return -1;

    /* and calculate when the timeout should fire. */
    then = now;
    timespec_add(&then, seconds);

    /* Find an unused timeout. */
    for (timeout = 0; timeout < TIMEOUTS; timeout++)
        if (!(__sync_fetch_and_or(&timeout_state[timeout], TIMEOUT_USED) & TIMEOUT_USED))
            break;

    /* No unused timeouts? */
    if (timeout >= TIMEOUTS)
        return -1;

    /* Clear all but TIMEOUT_USED from the state, */
    __sync_and_and_fetch(&timeout_state[timeout], TIMEOUT_USED);

    /* update the timeout details, */
    timeout_time[timeout] = then;

    /* and mark the timeout armable. */
    __sync_or_and_fetch(&timeout_state[timeout], TIMEOUT_ARMED);

    /* How long till the next timeout? */
    next = seconds;
    for (i = 0; i < TIMEOUTS; i++)
        if ((__sync_fetch_and_or(&timeout_state[i], 0) & (TIMEOUT_USED | TIMEOUT_ARMED | TIMEOUT_PASSED)) == (TIMEOUT_USED | TIMEOUT_ARMED)) {
            const double secs = timespec_diff(timeout_time[i], now);
            if (secs >= 0.0 && secs < next)
                next = secs;
        }

    /* Calculate duration when to fire the timeout next, */
    timespec_set(&when.it_value, next);
    when.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    when.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0L;

    /* and arm the timer. */
    if (timer_settime(timeout_timer, 0, &when, NULL)) {
        /* Failed. */
        __sync_and_and_fetch(&timeout_state[timeout], 0);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Return the timeout number. */
    return timeout;
}


static void timeout_signal_handler(int signum __attribute__((unused)), siginfo_t *info, void *context __attribute__((unused)))
{
    struct timespec   now;
    struct itimerspec when;
    int               saved_errno, i;
    double            next;

    /* Not a timer signal? */
    if (!info || info->si_code != SI_TIMER)
        return;

    /* Save errno; some of the functions used may modify errno. */
    saved_errno = errno;

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now)) {
        errno = saved_errno;
        return;
    }

    /* Assume no next timeout. */
    next = -1.0;

    /* Check all timeouts that are used and armed, but not passed yet. */
    for (i = 0; i < TIMEOUTS; i++)
        if ((__sync_or_and_fetch(&timeout_state[i], 0) & (TIMEOUT_USED | TIMEOUT_ARMED | TIMEOUT_PASSED)) == (TIMEOUT_USED | TIMEOUT_ARMED)) {
            const double  seconds = timespec_diff(timeout_time[i], now);
            if (seconds <= 0.0) {
                /* timeout [i] fires! */
                __sync_or_and_fetch(&timeout_state[i], TIMEOUT_PASSED);

            } else
            if (next <= 0.0 || seconds < next) {
                /* This is the soonest timeout in the future. */
                next = seconds;
            }
        }

    /* Note: timespec_set() will set the time to zero if next <= 0.0,
     *       which in turn will disarm the timer.
     * The timer is one-shot; it_interval == 0.
    */
    timespec_set(&when.it_value, next);
    when.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    when.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0L;
    timer_settime(timeout_timer, 0, &when, NULL);

    /* Restore errno. */
    errno = saved_errno;
}


int timeout_init(void)
{
    struct sigaction  act;
    struct sigevent   evt;
    struct itimerspec arm;

    /* Install timeout_signal_handler. */
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_sigaction = timeout_signal_handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    if (sigaction(TIMEOUT_SIGNAL, &act, NULL))
        return errno;

    /* Create a timer that will signal to timeout_signal_handler. */
    evt.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    evt.sigev_signo = TIMEOUT_SIGNAL;
    evt.sigev_value.sival_ptr = NULL;
    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &evt, &timeout_timer))
        return errno;

    /* Disarm the timeout timer (for now). */
    arm.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    arm.it_value.tv_nsec = 0L;
    arm.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    arm.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0L;
    if (timer_settime(timeout_timer, 0, &arm, NULL))
        return errno;

    return 0;
}

int timeout_done(void)
{
    struct sigaction  act;
    struct itimerspec arm;
    int               errors = 0;

    /* Ignore the timeout signals. */
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    if (sigaction(TIMEOUT_SIGNAL, &act, NULL))
        if (!errors) errors = errno;

    /* Disarm any current timeouts. */
    arm.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    arm.it_value.tv_nsec = 0L;
    arm.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    arm.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    if (timer_settime(timeout_timer, 0, &arm, NULL))
        if (!errors) errors = errno;

    /* Destroy the timer itself. */
    if (timer_delete(timeout_timer))
        if (!errors) errors = errno;

    /* If any errors occurred, set errno. */
    if (errors)
        errno = errors;

    /* Return 0 if success, errno otherwise. */
    return errors;
}
```

Remember to include the `rt` library when compiling, i.e. use `gcc -W -Wall *source*.c -lrt -o *binary*` to compile.

The idea is that the main program first calls `timeout_init()` to install all the necessary handlers et cetera, and may call `timeout_done()` to deistall it before exiting (or in a child process after `fork()`ing).

To set a timeout, you call `timeout_set(seconds)`. The return value is a timeout descriptor. Currently there is just a flag you can check using `timeout_passed()`, but the delivery of the timeout signal also interrupts any blocking I/O calls. Thus, you can expect the timeout to interrupt any blocking I/O call.

If you want to do anything more than set a flag at timeout, you cannot do it in the signal handler; remember, in a signal handler, you're limited to async-signal safe functions. The easiest way around that is to use a separate thread with an endless loop over `sigwaitinfo()`, with the `TIMEOUT_SIGNAL` signal blocked in all other threads. That way the dedicated thread is guaranteed to catch the signal, but at the same time, is not limited to async-signal safe functions. It can, for example, do much more work, or even send a signal to a specific thread using `pthread_kill()`. (As long as that signal has a handler, even one with an empty body, its delivery will interrupt any blocking I/O call in that thread.)

Here is a simple example `main()` for using the timeouts. It is silly, and relies on `fgets()` not retrying (when interrupted by a signal), but it seems to work.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char    buffer[1024], *line;
    int t1, t2, warned1;

    if (timeout_init()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "timeout_init(): %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    printf("You have five seconds to type something.\n");
    t1 = timeout_set(2.5); warned1 = 0;
    t2 = timeout_set(5.0);
    line = NULL;

    while (1) {

        if (timeout_passed(t1)) {
            /* Print only the first time we notice. */
            if (!warned1++)
                printf("\nTwo and a half seconds left, buddy.\n");
        }

        if (timeout_passed(t2)) {
            printf("\nAw, just forget it, then.\n");
            break;
        }

        line = fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
        if (line) {
            printf("\nOk, you typed: %s\n", line);
            break;
        }
    }

    /* The two timeouts are no longer needed. */
    timeout_unset(t1);
    timeout_unset(t2);

    /* Note: 'line' is non-NULL if the user did type a line. */

    if (timeout_done()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "timeout_done(): %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Bylos: Thanks for noticing the bug in `timeout_unset()`. The comment describing the intent of the `state` flag and timeout timer state change was really poor, so I fixed that too.

Comment: Good info and it can be updated to re-occuring timer with it_interval

Answer (score 3):

A useful read is the [time(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/time.7.html) man page. Notice that Linux also provides the [timerfd_create(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) Linux specific [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall), often used with a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or `ppoll(2)` or the older `select(2)` syscall).

If you want to use signals don't forget to read carefully [signal(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page (there are restrictions about coding signal handlers; you might want to set a `volatile sigatomic_t` variable in your signal handlers; you should not do any `new` or `delete` -or `malloc` & `free`- memory menagenment operations inside a signal handler, where only *async-safe* function calls are permitted.).

Notice also that event-oriented programming, such as GUI applications, often provide ways (in Gtk, in Qt, with `libevent`, ....) to manage timers in their event loop.