# Can I implement a single threaded timer in C?

Tags: c, linux, timer

I'm trying to implement a **communication protocol in C**. I need to **implement a timer** (so that if after some time an ACK has not been received yet, the sender will assume the packet has been lost and will send it again).

In a C-looking-pseudocode I would like to have something like this:

```
if (!ack_received(seqn) && timer_expired(seqn)) {
    send_packet(seqn);
    start_timer(seqn);
}
```

Note: `seqn` is the sequence number of the packet being sent. **Each packet needs a personal timer**.

How to implement `timer_expired` and `start_timer`? Is there a way to do it without using several threads?

Comment: Is the IO non-blocking?

Comment: Without a specific system in mind, the question is too broad. This will have to be done in system/OS-specific ways.

Comment: On which platform or operating system is this code running? Please **edit your question** to improve it (at least, by tagging it more precisely, e.g. *Linux*, *winapi* etc... )

Comment: If it's Linux then can use `timer_create()`, check this man page for [timer_create()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html)

Comment: One of [my old answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12765121/1475978) shows one possible approach. If the number of concurrent active timeouts is high, then using a min-heap for the absolute times would be much more efficient (for only a dozen or two slots, don't bother). Note that the example installs the timer signal handler without `SA_RESTART` flag, so its delivery will interrupt any blocking I/O operation (if you only have that one thread in the process).

Answer (score 1):

> Can I implement a single threaded timer in C?

Probably not in pure portable C99 (or single-threaded C11, see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).

But in practice, you'll often code for some [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), and you'll then get some ways to have timers. On Linux, read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) first. You'll probably also want to use a multiplexing call such as [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (to which you give a delay). And learn more about other [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), so read [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and some good Linux programming book (perhaps the old [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf), freely downloadable).

BTW, it seems that you are coding something network related. You practically need some API for that (e.g. [Berkeley sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets)), hence you'll probably use something similar to an OS.

Many [event loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) are single-threaded but are providing some kind of timers.

Or perhaps (if you don't have any OS) you are coding some freestanding C for some small embedded hardware platform (e.g. [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/)-like). Then you have some ways to poll network inputs and setup timers.

Comment: Alternatively in Windows you use [SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) together with WM_TIMER for the specific window. Not very accurate in my experience. Another alternative is to grab some HANDLE and then `WaitForSingleObject(some_handle, delay_ms);`. Works without implementing a WindowProc callback.

Answer (score 0):

depends of the architecture of your system it can be done more or less elegant way.

In the simple program with a single thread just declare the table containing starting timestamps. So the function will just check the difference between the current timestamp, the saved one and the timeout value. You need to implement of course an another function which will initialize the table element for the particular timeout counter.